# Bash Script - Wget fails

Tags: bash, wget

Currently i'm trying to get my script to download a mysql file from a website but it seems to go to a 302 redirect link. When i use the exact same link in my regular (windows) browser, it downloads the file.

Here's the output from the wget:

```
--2013-06-07 09:42:40--  http://6pp.kvdb.net/exports/mysql_sql.txt.gz
Resolving 6pp.kvdb.net... 2a01:7c8:eb:0:95:170:70:116, 212.78.187.48
Connecting to 6pp.kvdb.net|2a01:7c8:eb:0:95:170:70:116|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://www.d-centralize.nl/exports/mysql_sql.txt.gz [following]
--2013-06-07 09:42:40--  http://www.d-centralize.nl/exports/mysql_sql.txt.gz
Resolving www.d-centralize.nl... 2a00:1450:400c:c03::79, 173.194.66.121
Connecting to www.d-centralize.nl|2a00:1450:400c:c03::79|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2013-06-07 09:42:40 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

As you can see that http://6pp.kvdb.net/exports/mysql_sql.txt.gz this url downloads the file (in windows browser).

Comment: It works fine for me. It's probably a DNS issue.

Comment: It doesn't for me; I get a page titled `d-centralize | 404 Not found` saying "The requested page was not found. If you really expected it here, please leave us a note."

Comment: Same here, i don't think it's a DNS issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like 6pp.kvdb.net redirects to www.d-centralize.nl and www.d-centralize.nl has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address:

```
$ host www.d-centralize.nl
www.d-centralize.nl is an alias for ghs.google.com.
ghs.google.com is an alias for ghs.l.google.com.
ghs.l.google.com has address 173.194.69.121
ghs.l.google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4008:c01::79
```

Their webserver seems to be misconfigured. It is listening on both addresses, but serving files only on the IPv4 address. As your box is IPv6 enabled it will prefer the IPv6 address, which is the broken one.

Try `wget -4 ...` to force the IPv4 address of the server.